# How is fuel ignited in jet engines?

Tags: jet-engine, turbine

From what I understand, in jet engines, air is compressed and fuel is not only injected but also ignited : how is this done ?

Comment: Are you asking about when an engine is first started, or when it is already running?

Comment: @BowlOfRed : when it is already running

Comment: Ah yes, I think so ! I will try to learn a bit more about auto-ignition temperature. Thanks a lot @BowlOfRed !